# Where to close the file handler for read and write mode?

Tags: python

For example, I want to search some words for their contents and cache them into a file. This program may be run multiple times so each time new entries will be written into the file. for existing words, just return their contents without needing to redo the work.
For my code below, where is the place to close the file handler? Or is this the right way to do this job?

```
class Crawler(object):

    
    def __int__(self):
       
        self.file_handler = open('word.txt', 'a+')
        self.cache = self.load_words()
        
    def load_words(self):
        cache = {}
        
        for line in self.file_handler:
            columns = line.strip('\t')
            cache[columns[0]] = columns[1]
            
        return cache
    
    def search(self, word):
        # 1. return word's content immediately
        if word in self.cache:
            return self.cache[word]
        
        # 2. Otherwise, fetch the word's content
        content = get_content(word)
        
        # 3. Append the new word-content pair into the cache file
        self.file_handler.write(word + '\t' + content)
        self.cache[word] = content
        
        return content
```

Comment: The file handle will be closed when the `Crawler` object is deleted.  That's fine; as long as the object exists, you want the file to be available.

Comment: @TimRoberts, In the past sometimes if I don't close the handler for writing, the content isn't written to the file, so I always use the 'with open(file_path, 'w') as f' format. Why is that?

Comment: The content will always be written.  If you try to read the file within the same application without closing it, then you have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Robert said: your file will be closed automatically when it's garbage collected.

As for your question in the comments, you need to flush the buffer so it's written in the file. when you close a file it does this automatically.

Here are a couple link going into a bit more details:

[destructors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/)

[File Flushing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm#:%7E:text=Python%20file%20method%20flush(),data%20before%20closing%20any%20file.)

Comment: In my case above, where to flush it in the code?

Comment: you can flush at the end of your search function

Comment: So flush for each writing.

Comment: if you're not deleting the object right away after and you wanna update the file in "realtime" i think this is the way to go.